# PHP Error -- Use of undefined constant x - assumed 'x'

Tags: php, json, angularjs, laravel

### how to get data from table and pass it in controller in json format and get those data in view using angularjs

I want to get data from `json` encoded variable from controller and show it to view page using `angularjs`

view page using angularjs

```
<div class="card"  ng-app = "myApp">
  <table class="table table-hover" ng-controller = "menuController">
     <thead>
        <tr>
           <th>Name</th>
           <th>Parent menu</th>
           <th>Order</th>
           <th>Status</th>
           <th class="text-center">Actions</th>
        </tr>
     </thead>
     <tbody>
        <tr ng-repeat = "x  in values">
           <td>{{x.name}}</td>
           <td>{{x.parent_name}}</td>
           <td>{{x.orders}}</td>
           <td>{{x.status}}</td>
           <td class="text-right">
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-icon-toggle"
                      data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top"
                      data-original-title="Edit row">
                <i class="fa fa-pencil"></i>
              </button>
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-icon-toggle"
                      data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top"
                      data-original-title="Copy row">
                 <i class="fa fa-copy"></i>
              </button>
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-icon-toggle"
                      data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" 
                      data-original-title="Delete row">
                <i class="fa fa-trash-o"></i>
              </button>
           </td>
        </tr>
     </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

```
  var app = angular.module('myApp');
  app.controller('menuController',function ($scope,$http) {
     $scope.values = ["Milk", "Bread", "Cheese"];
  });
```

PHP controller  code

```
public function getmenu(){

    $records=Menu::all();

    return json_encode($records);
    }
```

route code

```
Route::group(['prefix'=>'admin'],function(){
    Route::get('/form','HomeController@form');
});
```

> ErrorException (E_ERROR)
> Use of undefined constant x - assumed 'x' (this will throw an Error in a future version of PHP) (View:form.blade.php)

Answer (score 1):

I think it might be because you are serving your view which contains the angular code with Laravel, and in the file `form.blade.php` you use the angular syntax, which is the same as the blade one.

To solve that, you can try to remove `blade` word from the view filename, so it would become `form.php` or (alternative way instead of modifying the filename) each time you have to print something with the JavaScript framework instead of blade, use: `@{{ variableToPrint }}`.

So for example, part of your loop would become:

```html
<tr ng-repeat="x in values">
       <td>@{{x.name}}</td>
       <td>@{{x.parent_name}}</td>
       <td>@{x.orders}}</td>
       <td>@{{x.status}}</td>
       <!-- ... -->
```

You get the error as blade uses the same syntax to evaluate and print values, so if you write: `{{ x.name }}` blade finds a string literal `x` which gets interpreted as a constant.
If you prefix the `@` sign, blade will recognize that as an instruction not to be parsed, but that needs to be left as it is, it would just remove the `@`, leaving you with the correct code for you JavaScript loop